# Convert varchar column to date

Tags: sql

I have one column `LogDate` which is `varchar(2000)` type. I want this column as date type. Current table format `2014-03-31 09:13:03.000`.

How can I do that?

Comment: cast(LogDate as date), or perhaps cast(LogDate as timestamp)

Comment: How would you like the output to be saved?

Comment: Which is the version of SQL Server? What exactly do you need - from your question I got impresion that you need to change the type of the column to date?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Data type casting is highly dependent on the DBMS

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using SQL Server:

```
declare @LogDate varchar(2000)

set @LogDate = '2014-03-31 09:13:03.000'

select convert (datetime, @LogDate, 21)
```

Full table query at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/58a3f/1/0

Answer (score 0):

If all the records in the table having data in correct format(i.e all are date only, no characters) then you can directly alter the column data type to DATE type:

```
ALTER TABLE <table name> ALTER COLUMN LogDate date
```